# Writing and Reading simultaneously from a protobuf format file in two different processes

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

With the protobuf-net library I'm trying to serialize a series of object (shown below) and writing a file, and at the same time, read it from another process as soon as there are any bytes available to read from the file.

Obviously the "Person" class is just a class to demonstrate more or less what my real class looks like

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class Person
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Incremental number of data
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public List<int> GenericNumbers {get; set;}
    }
```

Assuming the file is created in this way:

```
file = File.Open("d:\\testWriting\\test.out", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

I used the following pieces of code:

**To Write** a file in *process A*:

```
    public WriteToFile(string file)
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, person, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
    }
```

This method is called in a loop so that I can write a certain number of records to the same file.

At the same time, in *process B* I open the same file and try **to read** the data:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream("d:\\testWriting\\test.out", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    Person person = null;

                while (true)
                {                     
                    person = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(fileStream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                    if (person != null)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"\r{person.Id}"); //Id is an incremental number
                    }
                    else
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                }
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Initially I can read the file, but if during the writing process I set a pause or a delay such that reading is faster than writing, it shows an error like this:

> **System.IO.EndOfStreamException**: 'Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream.'

or like this:

> **ProtoBuf.ProtoException**: 'Sub-message not read correctly (end 24 vs 19)'

As can be seen from the errors shown, I'm trying to deserialize an incomplete object. But the question is:

- Is there a (performant) way to understand when the record is incomplete so as to wait to deserialize the data after a few seconds?
- Using the ProtoReader class, could I insert some options in order to handle this type of "exception"?

Comment: You'd better use a [pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations) or a [channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels) instead of a file

Comment: @shingo no, it needs to read from file

Answer (score 0):

You already have a length delimiter, so you can use the size info to make sure that there are enough bytes available.

For performance sensitive use cases you could use memory mapped files and write the delimiter after writing the content. Maybe take a look at [Aeron.NET](https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/Aeron.NET) or search for inter-process communications (IPC) using files.